# How to decorate SwiftUI Views depending on condition?

Tags: swiftui, watchos

This is what I mean:

```
var body: some View {
    Text(text)
        .font(Font.openSansLight(withSize: 15))
        .foregroundColor(Color(uiColor: mode.underlayTextColor))
    if scale { //this is a Bool value passed to initializer
        .scaledToFill() //Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'scaledToFill'
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
        .lineLimit(1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example above, you can use the ternary operator in the modifier parameter for `.minimumScaleFactor` and `.lineLimit`, e.g.

```
.minimumScaleFactor(scale ? 0.5 : 1)
.lineLimit(scale ? 1 : nil)
```

`scaledToFill` doesn't take a parameter, so you could create you're own modifier that does, e.g.

```
struct ScaledToFill: ViewModifier {
    
    let scale: Bool
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if scale {
            content.scaledToFill()
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func scaledToFill(_ scale: Bool) -> some View {
        modifier(ScaledToFill(scale: scale))
    }
}
```

then use it like:

```
.scaledToFill(scale)
```

Also see [this](https://www.objc.io/blog/2021/08/24/conditional-view-modifiers/) for an example of a "conditional modifier" and why not to use it.

Comment: Nice one for pointing out the objcio article 